# How to start and close a MS Edge Browser

Tags: .net, vb.net, microsoft-edge

I want to start an MS Edge browser and close it after a few moments.
I've tried some things like the Microsoft Internet Controls.
But I need a different browser than the IE.

```vb
Dim pi As New Process
pi = Process.Start("shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge")
Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
pi.CloseMainWindow() ' -> NullReferenceException
```

But I always get a null reference exception even if I've initialized it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the process using **GetProcessesByName** and then try to kill it.

Example code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://localhost/")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim p As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdge")
        For i = 0 To p.Count - 1
            p(i).Kill()
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Output:

[image]

Let me know if I misunderstood anything. I will try to correct myself.

Comment: No, that's actually completly fine but the Reason I'm closing the browser is to clear all tabs. Actually, ending the task will restore all opened tabs. So even your answer is correct to my initiated question, I'm looking for something different. Process.Close or Process.MainWindowsClose is sadly not working. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use Microsoft WebDriver. It can help to solve your requirement for automating the Edge browser. Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/